# Why doesn't the gravitational potential energy and the gravitational acceleration yield the same velocity?

Tags: energy, gravity

This might be a really dumb question, but I am having trouble figuring it out. Imagine a small object revolving around a planet. The acceleration of the object due to the planet is $ \frac F {m_2} = \frac{Gm_1}{r^2}$, so the tangential velocity $v$ is $\sqrt{\frac {Gm_1}{r}}$. I have also learned that the the gravitational potential energy is $\frac {Gm_1m_2}{r}$. If we convert this to kinetic energy  $\frac 1 2 m_2v^2$, and solve for $v$ we get $v=\sqrt{2\frac {Gm_1}{r}}$. Where is the 2 coming from? Did I make a mistake in assuming I can convert the potential energy to kinetic energy?

Comment: You may find these articles helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_orbital_energy There's also relevant info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem but that article covers a lot of territory, and is a bit chaotic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that procedure doesn't make sense.  If I hold a 1 kg mass 2 meters off of the ground it has about 20 J of potential energy, assuming that I choose the potential energy to be zero at ground level.  Can I convert that to kinetic energy in order to determine its current speed?

It's also worth noting that the gravitational potential energy formula is $U(r) = \color{red}{\mathbf-} \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r}$, where we have chosen $U(\infty)=0$.

The kinetic energy (and corresponding speed) you have calculated does have an interpretation - it's the speed an object would have once it reached the radial position $r$ if you released it from rest at $R_0\rightarrow \infty$.  More carefully, if you release an object from rest in space and let it fall towards Earth, its speed at $r$ increases as the release point gets further away.  The speed you calculated is the upper limit of these impact speeds.

Comment: What if we assume that the object is slowly spiraling towards the planet such that the initial conditions are 0 potential and kinetic energy, but at point r it starts to go in a circular motion around the planet? Or if the planet suddenly teleported when it was r away from the object to a place perpendicular to the object's trajectory r distance away? The change in potential energy would equal the change in kinetic energy, at least in the first case. I am still unsure how the equation fails.

Comment: @folopolo The first velocity you calculated is the velocity of a particle in a circular orbit of radius $r$ around a planet of mass $M$.  This can be calculated because to maintain a circular orbit, the particle needs to have a particular speed.  The second velocity you calculated is the velocity of a particle which started at spatial infinity and is about to impact the planet.  I am not certain why you think they should have anything to do with one another.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks

Comment: "the speed an object would have once it reached the surface of the planet" Not exactly. It is the speed with which the object would reach the planet if I were a point mass.

Comment: @my2cts The question is predicated on the idea of a small mass in orbit around the planet, so I'm comfortable making that tacit approximation here.

Comment: @J.Murray My comment should have read: the speed reached when crossing the orbit after falling from infinity.

Comment: @my2cts Okay, agreed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You con't convert all of the potential energy into kinetic energy. If the object is revolving around a planet the object still has potential energy based on how high above planet it revolves.